# Can I do (x_i-x_j)^T(x_i-x_j) for x_i, x_j are rows in a X matrix with numpy native function instead of loop

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, vectorization

I need to compute [image: (x_i-x_j)^T(x_i-x_j)] in numpy where $x_i$ and $x_j$ are rows in a matrix $X$. Now I am using loop, which is very slow. Is there any numpy native function allows such computation, like einsum:

```
n=X.shape[0]
Y=np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(n):
    x=(X-X[i])**2
    x=np.sum(x, axis=1)
    Y[i]=x
return Y
```

BTW, I am very confused with einsum. Is there any good material for its introduction. The manual page on numpy was not very clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1**

You can use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) as a `vectorized` approach -

```
import numpy as np
Y = np.sum((X - X[:,None,:])**2,2)
```

This should be efficient with relatively smaller input arrays.

---

**Approach #2**

Seems like you are performing euclidean distance calculations and getting the squared distances. So, you can use [`distance.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) like so -

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance
Y = distance.cdist(X, X, 'sqeuclidean')
```

This should be efficient with large input arrays.

Comment: this works perfect and l should really spend a little more time to understand broadcasting. However, surprisingly it runs actually slower than my function, and of course use much more memory.

Comment: @tabasco Would use more memory for sure. Need to run runtime tests though. What datasize are you working with for the input, X?

Comment: X is a 20000x200 matrix and I suppose `X - X[:,None,:]` expands it to a 20000x20000x200 matrix, which is too huge. That is understandable but I didn't expect this runs slower than the loop function, when I test it with a X of 2000 rows

Comment: @tabasco Test out the just added Approach #2?

Comment: Approach #2 works great. I didn't realize I am computing euclidean distance. Thanks a lot.